# First website, only index.html page loads

Tags: html, file, http

I have made my first website and in the preview in Safari and Chrome from Dreamweaver it works fine. But after uploading my files with Filezilla to 000webhost and typing in the URL, only the index page loads, links to other pages on the site don't work, images are broken and the css isn't applied.

I'm think it is because I haven't named the files correctly in the code, but I have no idea what to call them in order to get it right.

The file you upload to is public_html. So I've tried http://www.webaddress/public_html/Pages/entertainment.html but it didn't change anything.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You probably need to remove the /public_html from the URL

Comment: So links to other pages do *work* but CSS/images on these page don’t work? Or do you get a 404 error when trying to visit another page?

Comment: are you sure you used relative path and not complete path?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure, for example there are links to the app store and to Facebook that work fine, but links that are on a navbar to other pages in the site haven't worked

Answer (score 0):

Without code examples it's very difficult to answer this, but it's probably just that your URL format is incorrect.

For example, if you've got `example.com/example/example.html` and that page contains a CSS file with a location of `/css/style.css`, the web browser will look for `example.com/css/style.css` because the slash at the beginning of the URL tells it to go to the root.

In this case, your CSS file is probably actually in `example.com/example/css/style.css`. Remove the beginning slash so the location is `css/style.css` and the web browser will look for the file using the current page's location as it's starting point.

Comment: These are the two types that I was trying:

The second one is where the files are located on my computer, I don't really understand if the code should link to my files or the page that they will show up on e.g. below food.html

<li><a href="http://cheepcheepapp.comlu.com/public_html/index.html" class="thispage">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="/Users/Owen/Documents/owen ralph 10316809/Pages/food.html">Food</a></li>

Thanks again, much appreciated

Comment: OK, having gone to your website it's clear what the issue is. Your URLs are all pointing to locations on your computer. You shouldn't use full URLs if possible, instead use relative ones. For example, instead of `<a href="/Users/Owen/Documents/owen ralph 10316809/Pages/food.html">Food</a>` it should be something like `<a href="/Pages/food.html">Food</a>` (or wherever that file can be found on your server). That way, the URLs will work no matter what server or computer they're on.

Comment: Just to clear up another point of confusion, `public_html` is the folder that your web server uses to determine what the public should see. Some web servers will use things like `httpdocs`, `htdocs`, etc instead. In all cases, that folder should never be included in your URLs. As far as public access goes, `/example.com/public_html/index.html` is equivalent to `example.com/index.html`. This is so you can store things the public *shouldn't* have access to, such as server logs.